# The multi-part identifier "xxx" could not be bound

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, stored-procedures

The following is a `HAVING` clause from a small part of a very large stored procedure which I have inherited from some other devs (external);

```
HAVING (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.ContractDailyRoomAllocation da2
    WHERE da2.ContractId = DA.ContractId
    AND da2.RoomTypeId = DA.RoomTypeId
    AND da2.Date >= @FromDate AND da2.Date < @ToDate
    AND da2.IsSold = 0
    AND da2.ReleaseDay <= DATEDIFF("d", @TodayDate, da2.Date)) T) = @StayDates
    AND ( (@AllowOnRequestBookings = 'False' 
      OR dbo.GetAvailablePackageRoomCount(da2.ContractId,da2.RoomTypeId,@FromDate,@ToDate)  
      >= 0 ) )
      AND ( (@AllowOnRequestBookings = 'True' 
      OR dbo.GetAvailablePackageRoomCount(da2.ContractId,da2.RoomTypeId,@FromDate,@ToDate) 
      > 0 )
)
```

The last 2 `AND`'s give me the following error messages:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetAvailableHotelRooms, Line 176
>   The multi-part identifier "da2.ContractId" could not be bound.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetAvailableHotelRooms, Line 176
>   The multi-part identifier "da2.RoomTypeId" could not be bound.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetAvailableHotelRooms, Line 177
>   The multi-part identifier "da2.ContractId" could not be bound.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetAvailableHotelRooms, Line 177
>   The multi-part identifier "da2.RoomTypeId" could not be bound.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Reformatting your code shows the problem. All I have changed is whitespace and added a comment:

```
HAVING
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
        (
            SELECT *
            FROM dbo.ContractDailyRoomAllocation da2 -- <-- da2 defined here
            WHERE da2.ContractId = DA.ContractId
            AND da2.RoomTypeId = DA.RoomTypeId
            AND da2.Date >= @FromDate AND da2.Date < @ToDate
            AND da2.IsSold = 0
            AND da2.ReleaseDay <= DATEDIFF("d", @TodayDate, da2.Date)
        ) T
    ) = @StayDates
AND
    ( 
        (
            @AllowOnRequestBookings = 'False' OR
            dbo.GetAvailablePackageRoomCount(da2.ContractId,da2.RoomTypeId,@FromDate,@ToDate) >= 0

        )
    )
AND 
    (
        (
            @AllowOnRequestBookings = 'True' OR
            dbo.GetAvailablePackageRoomCount(da2.ContractId,da2.RoomTypeId,@FromDate,@ToDate) > 0
        )
    )
```

As can now easily be seen, `da2` is an alias defined in the subquery in the *first* `AND`d term, and so is not available in other terms.

It may be that you want to move the second and third `AND`d terms here *into* the subquery, or it might be more complicated than that.

Answer (score 3):

You have declared the alias `da2` inside a subquery,
then you referenced it outside of that subquery, where it is not recognized.

if you need "The last 2 `AND`'s" as a filter of table `T` (the records that will be counted),
then try using this instead:

```
HAVING 
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM dbo.ContractDailyRoomAllocation da2
    WHERE da2.ContractId = DA.ContractId
        AND da2.RoomTypeId = DA.RoomTypeId
        AND da2.Date >= @FromDate AND da2.Date < @ToDate
        AND da2.IsSold = 0
        AND da2.ReleaseDay <= DATEDIFF("d", @TodayDate, da2.Date
        AND ( @AllowOnRequestBookings = 'False' OR dbo.GetAvailablePackageRoomCount(da2.ContractId,da2.RoomTypeId,@FromDate,@ToDate) >= 0 )
        AND ( @AllowOnRequestBookings = 'True' OR dbo.GetAvailablePackageRoomCount(da2.ContractId,da2.RoomTypeId,@FromDate,@ToDate) > 0 )
    ) = @StayDates
```

Please make sure that it is the data you are expecting,
and let me know if it is something else that you need.

רועי גביש